# limit_req_zone in regards to the bucket name

Tags: nginx

If I were to use

```
limit_req_zone  $http_api_key  zone=one:10m   rate=1r/s;
```

What would happen if I did *not* have the api-key header? Would that be a null bucket thats collective or would it not apply itself to the limit_req_zone? Or would I need an evil IF to check if the $http_api_key exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who were wondering, and hopefully this helps someone in the future, I found the answer through the source code:

https://github.com/git-mirror/nginx/blob/a3035758763a75f3df7d529c897528eb65c84c09/src/http/modules/ngx_http_limit_req_module.c#L194

```
    if (vv == NULL || vv->not_found) {
        continue;
    }
```

vv being the bucket's value. nginx will simply ignore and continue on which is ideal for my needs.